# Best practices for Informatica Webservice workflow

Tags: workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter, parameterized

I have created a Informatica webservice workflow which takes 1 parameter as input. A Webservice provider source definition is used for this and mapping is a one-way type.

Workflow works fine when parameter is being passed. But when the same workflow is triggered from Informatica Power center directly (in which case no parameters are passed), mapping that contains webservice provider source definition takes 3 minutes to complete (Gives Timeout based commit point in the log).

Is it a good practice to run the webservice workflow from power center directly? And is there a way to improve its performance when triggered from power center directly?

Note: I am trying to use 1 workflow for both - 1) Pass the parameter from web 2) Schedule the workflow in Informatica

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions below.

*Is it a good practice to run the webservice workflow from power center directly?*
Of course it depends on requirement - whether you need to extract data automatically from WS or not. If you pass parameter using some session then i dont see much issue here and your session is completing within time.
So, you can create a new session/command task/shell script to create a param file and then use it in original session so it is passed on to WS.
In a complex scenario, you may have to pass multiple values, in such case, i would recommend to use a parent workflow to call original workflow multiple times and change param every time before call.

*Is there a way to improve its performance when triggered from power center directly?*
It is really depends on few factors.

1. The web service - Make sure you are using correct input and output columns. Most of the time WS are sensitive to outside call and you need to choose optimized column to extract data for better performance. You can work with WS admin to know correct column.
2. If informatica flow is complex then depending on bottle neck transformation/s (source, target, expression, lookup, aggregator, sorter), we can check and take actions.
   For lookup, you can add new filter to exclude unwanted data, remove unwanted columns etc.
   For aggregator, you can use sorter before to improve perf.
   ... like this